# How do i highlight a row based on another row condition in react jsx?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, jsx

I need to highlight rows in red color if the value of the ratio (column) is equal to or greater than 0.96. I was not sure where to add the lines to make these changes. Can anyone help me with this? I am trying to highlight the rows with red color where the condition satisfies. i.e. if the ratio value is greater than or equal to 0.96.

Here is the code I have:

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import { AppContext } from "../../context/AppContext";
import { getCostSales} from "../../API/api";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import Table from "react-bootstrap/Table";

const CostSales = () => {
  const {
    userRole,
    employee,
    setUserRole,
    setEmployee,
    isLoggedIn,
    setIsLoggedIn
  } = useContext(AppContext);

  const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([]);

  // TODO: conditional render for table? or can show table headers at least?
  const onHandleRunCostSales = () => {
    //call API/api method here
    console.log("Run below cost sales report clicked:");
    getCostSales().then((res) => {
      if (res) {
        setTableData(res);
        console.log("res in below cost sales report: ", res);
      }
    });
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {userRole === "Manager" || userRole === "Owner" ? (
        <div>
          <Button variant="primary" onClick={onHandleRunCostSales}>
            Run Report
          </Button>
          {tableData ? (
            <div>
              <Table>
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Vin</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Invoice Price</th>
                    <th>Sold Price</th>
                    <th>Ratio</th>
                    <th>Customer Name</th>
                    <th>SalesPerson</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  {tableData.map((rowData, index) => (
                    <tr>
                      <td>{rowData.vin}</td>
                      <td>{rowData.date}</td>
                      <td> {rowData.invoice_price} </td>
                      <td>{rowData.sold_price}</td>
                      <td>{rowData.ratio}</td>
                      <td>{rowData.customer_name}</td>
                      <td>{rowData.salesperson}</td>
                    </tr>
                  ))}
                </tbody>
              </Table>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <div>
              <p>No data available for report</p>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <p>Sorry, we can't show you this page</p>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default CostSales;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the conditional style for `tr` element based on ratio

Update: you can have util method to decide on color based on ration

```
function highlightColor(ratio) {
  if (ratio > 0.98) {
    return "green";
  } else if (ratio >= 0.96) {
    return "red";
  }
  return "white";
}

<tbody>
  {tableData.map((rowData, index) => (
    <tr style={{ backgroundColor: highlightColor(rowData.ratio) }}>
      <td>{rowData.vin}</td>
      <td>{rowData.date}</td>
      <td> {rowData.invoice_price} </td>
      <td>{rowData.sold_price}</td>
      <td>{rowData.ratio}</td>
      <td>{rowData.customer_name}</td>
      <td>{rowData.salesperson}</td>
    </tr>
  ))}
</tbody>;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Okay, if i had one more condition. Say, if the ratio is greater than 0.98 highlight green. How do i do that?

Comment: @emma19, Updated the answer. you can have the helper method to decide the color.

Comment: Also, the date is in unix timestamp, example: 1607110465663 is there a way to convert it to datetime format?

Comment: Unix ts is seconds, so conver to milliseconds. new Date(ts * 1000), will have js date